# is there any good way to pass error object in rest api

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, npm, logic

i got error object :
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
type of (err) : Object

now i wanna pass this object to another web service (restapi)

1. what content type will it need ?
2. how to pass whole error object in body of rest api ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard content type when sending a error response. You can select any content type as you wish. In this case you may use status code `500 Server Error`. You can access the error message by `error.message`